# SQL CLR aggregate parameters

Tags: sql-server, clr, aggregate

Here is an example of using a `SqlUserDefinedAggregate`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91e6taax(v=vs.80).aspx

Which allows you to do:

```
SELECT LastName, COUNT(LastName) AS CountOfLastName, dbo.CountVowels(LastName) AS CountOfVowels
FROM Person.Contact
GROUP BY LastName
ORDER BY LastName
```

How could I convert this to `dbo.CountLetters(LastName, 'listOfLetters')`?  In other words, how can I take an extra parameter when aggregating values?  This is easy with a regular CLR function, but how to do it here escapes me.  Thanks!

Comment: I can't believe I got two upvotes when I had forgotten to link to the example.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what version you're running. For SQL Server 2005 you can't as the input is restricted to a single parameter. For 2008, see [this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=2022) for an example.

Comment: That's just what I was looking for; too bad I'm using version 2005.  Through your link I did find this article with a workaround: http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=2043.  It's very much a hack so we'll see what I end up doing...